# the parallax layers are split and you see the layers between the parallax section and the next content section

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a website inspired by the page: https://www.firewatchgame.com/ the issue is that when I make the screen smaller, it happens what happens here

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".scene").forEach((elem) => {
  const modifier = elem.getAttribute("data-modifier");

  basicScroll
    .create({
      elem: elem,
      from: 0,
      to: 519,
      direct: true,
      props: {
        "--translateY": {
          from: "0",
          to: `${10 * modifier}px`,
        },
      },
    })
    .start();
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
  background: black;
}

.scene {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(var(--translateY));
  will-change: transform;
}
```

```html
<div id="parallax">
  <img class="scene" data-modifier="30" src="https://s.electerious.com/parallaxscene/p0.png">
  <img class="scene" data-modifier="18" src="https://s.electerious.com/parallaxscene/p1.png">
  <img class="scene" data-modifier="12" src="https://s.electerious.com/parallaxscene/p2.png">
  <img class="scene" data-modifier="8" src="https://s.electerious.com/parallaxscene/p3.png">
  <img class="scene" data-modifier="6" src="https://s.electerious.com/parallaxscene/p4.png">
  <img class="scene" data-modifier="0" src="https://s.electerious.com/parallaxscene/p6.png">
</div>
<div id="test">
  <font color="red">This is some text!asdfasd</font>
</div>

<script src="https://s.electerious.com/basicScroll/dist/basicScroll.min.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ufcqw2xh/

That it opens a section between the parallax layers and the next section, and the parallax layers are looked at.
my question is: how could I fix it or also how could I make the screen smaller, the parallax layers do what fire watch does that the image is shortened horizontally only. thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say images are 'shortened horizontally only' you mean that they are cropped evenly from the left and the right with the height remaining constant? Note that below a certain width the fire watch site brings in a different image, it doesn't just continue to crop. Is that what you require?

Comment: yes, I mean that they are cropped evenly from the left and right with a constant height, I understand the other image because it is for mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement is to keep the vertical size of the image, altering its width as necessary. There is also a problem with a 'gap' showing on certain viewport sizes between the scene and the background (a lower scene shows through as a sort of yellow).

If we change the `width: 100%` setting of the scenes to `min-width: 100%` the height remains constant and the width gets shortened as the viewport changes. The 'gap' problem disappears.

This is not an absolutely complete answer because the shortening is from the right (which actually suits the given scene because the wolf is towards the left) but for a more general solution you'd probably want to investigate further, perhaps using object-fit in some way.

Note also that the documentation says that calculate should be run on any resizing. This didn't seem to effect this change, but might be important for other changes.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".scene").forEach((elem) => {
  const modifier = elem.getAttribute("data-modifier");

  basicScroll
    .create({
      elem: elem,
      from: 0,
      to: 519,
      direct: true,
      props: {
        "--translateY": {
          from: "0",
          to: `${10 * modifier}px`,
        },
      },
    })
    .start();
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
  background: black;
}

.scene {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(var(--translateY));
  will-change: transform;
  }
```

```html
<div id="parallax">
  <img class="scene" data-modifier="30" src="https://s.electerious.com/parallaxscene/p0.png">
  <img class="scene" data-modifier="18" src="https://s.electerious.com/parallaxscene/p1.png">
  <img class="scene" data-modifier="12" src="https://s.electerious.com/parallaxscene/p2.png">
  <img class="scene" data-modifier="8" src="https://s.electerious.com/parallaxscene/p3.png">
  <img class="scene" data-modifier="6" src="https://s.electerious.com/parallaxscene/p4.png">
  <img class="scene" data-modifier="0" src="https://s.electerious.com/parallaxscene/p6.png">
</div>
<div id="test">
  <font color="red">This is some text!asdfasd</font>
</div>

<script src="https://s.electerious.com/basicScroll/dist/basicScroll.min.js"></script>
```